# Secondary Magento 1.7 Store (Same CSS)

Tags: admin, multistore, store-view

I created a store formatted already how I want everything to look.

Then I went to AdminPanel-->System-->ManageStores and I created a 
Website, Store, and Store View

When I visit the secondary website all the CSS/formatting returns to default Magento settings.  Is there a way I can carry over all the css from our main website?

If you have any questions or need clarification please let me know.

What I've tried so far is:

**Admin Panel --> System --> Configuration**

Change the Current Configuration Scope: to my secondary store

For **GENERAL-->Web** under **Secure** and **Unsecure**

I unchecked "Use Default" for the following,

Base Skin URL: http://firstwebsite.com/skin/ 
Base Media URL: http://firstwebsite.com/media/ 
Base JavaScript URL: http://firstwebsite.com/js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why would you want to do that as the CSS is on the server so as long as you have assigned the theme in

System -> Configuration -> Design

Select your new store from the Current Configuration Select drop down and you can assign you css and images / layouts and templates here per store

Comment: We don't have a theme for our Main Website just css/js/media files.  The reason we want to share store layout is because a lot of the same products are being sold/carried over but more of a limited selection for the secondary store

Comment: For example even our Company logo isn't displaying because for the secondary website it doesn't know where to look for media images

Comment: Yes if you do what i said in my answer it will display the same images/css and layouts on site 2 as it does on site 1

Comment: under Design-->Themes in Skin I unchecked "Use Default" then put http://firstwebsite.com/skin/ and saved but nothing changed is this what you meant?

Comment: no you have to put theme folder in it those fields

Comment: sorry not sure I follow, but if this works i'll be sure to upvote your answer. Thanks for taking the time to respond back, can you give me an example of what could go in these fields? Wouldn't they have to be a file path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51904/discussion-between-dava-gordon-and-codingmagesheen).